# Is this regular expression written correctly?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Why does this code match characters like "Æ" - isn't this character not in the range stated below?

```
preg_match('/[\x4E-\x9F]+[\w\d]*/i', $char);
```

Comment: Depends on how you use that `preg_match` call. It only works if you really test character-wise. It does not verify the whole line or input string to conform (lacks `^` and `$`). Also you didn't elaborate on your expected charset.

Comment: I test some chinese character and some weird character. Thats why I wonder why weird character as Æ allowed too. So I just realise it is problem, it should not really allow chinese character, but somehow, chinese character is allowed under this expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codes below works well with allow only chinese character in the stated range as input.

```
preg_match('/^[\x{4E00}-\x{9FA5}]*$/u', $charChineseOnly)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your regular expression assumes each character is represented by a single byte, but I'm guessing your strings actually use multibyte encoding.

UTF-8, for instance, uses two bytes for the Æ character, so `"Æ"` will actually be represented as a two-byte string equivalent to `"\xc3\x86"`, your pattern will match it because its second byte falls into the `\x4E-\x9F` range.

If your character encoding is indeed UTF-8, your problem can be solved by appending the "u" modifier to your patterns (`/.../u`) and using [Unicode character properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) instead of byte ranges.

Comment: Thanks for your information. \u is working.
I tried with "u" modifier, it is work, but with \x4E00-\x9FA5 together.
Code below works well as allowed chinese characters and it is not allowed other characters out of this range(4E00-9FA5) in Unicode table, tested with korean characters, weird characters, symbol, english etc, it not allowed these except chinese characters in range below:

preg_match('/[\x{4E00}-\x{9FA5}]/u', $char)

Answer (score 0):

That code doesn't match characters like `Æ` on its own, as it is out of the range you specified (for reference, that character is `\xC6`).

For example, this code:

```
$char = "Æ";
echo (preg_match('/[\x4E-\x9F]+[\w\d]*/i', $char) ? "Found" : "Not Found");
```

prints "Not Found" when I run it.

What is the value of the `$char` variable? The name implies that there is only a single character in the variable, but if there are more characters, and *those* characters match the pattern, then `preg_match` will return true.

If you want to use check if your entire variable matches that pattern, then you need to use delimiters to mark the beginning and end of the string - `^` denotes the beginning of a string and/or line, and `$` matches the end.

Try this:

```
preg_match('/^[\x4E-\x9F]+[\w\d]*$/i', $char);
```

Comment: Ya, it is \xC6. 
I tried preg_match('/^[\x4E-\x9F]+[\w\d]*$/i', $char); it shown as not in range now, but now it not allowed chinese characters too, why? as before allowed chinese character.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that character is. Look at the [ASCII chart](http://www.asciitable.com/). That pattern will match any string which contains one or more `N` to `ƒ` and is followed by 0 or more word characters. It is a bit redundant though `\w` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]`, which means `\w\d` is `[a-zA-Z0-90-9_-]`.

Comment: But then why it could allow chinese character somehow?

Answer (score 0):

That character range looks completely zany, so if I am allowed to guess based on that; no, it is not correct.  What do you want/expect `[\x4e-\x9f]` to match?

Comment: That is hardly going to work. 4E is the ASCII code for the Latin letter N, so 4E-7F is unambiguously 7-bit ASCII, I think in any representation available to PHP (though I am by no means an expert in CJK++) and the meaning of 80-9F is also Latin if you are working in Unicode. In what character set / encoding would you be working?

Comment: UTF-8 .
And the range i expected actually is in Unicode table 4E00 until 9FA5 .